# Generate vertices and normals for a flat shaded cylinder

Tags: rust, computational-geometry, graphics, opengl

I would like to generate list of vertices and normals (with the correct indices) for rendering a cylinder barrel (I ommited the end caps for brevity).

The normals should not be interpolated (flat shaded cylinder), so all four vertices that form a radial segment must have the same normal.

Currently this is achieved by first generating a ring of vertices on the top and the bottom of the cylinder barrel and then another ring of vertices, shifted by one radial segment and with a shifted normal.

This current function works fine, but I do not like that I have to calculate some values (`u`, `theta`, `sin_theta`, `cos_theta`) more than once and that I needed two loops for doing this.

```rust
fn print_cylinder_vertices(
    radius_bottom: f32, 
    radius_top: f32, 
    height: f32, 
    radial_segments: u32
) {
    // The vertices and indices of the cylinder barrel.
    let mut verts = Vec::new();
    let mut inds = Vec::new();

    // Helper variables.
    let half_height = height / 2f32;

    // Calculate the slope so that the normals can be easily derived.
    let slope = (radius_bottom - radius_top) / height;

    for y in 0..=HEIGHT_SEGMENTS {
        let radius = y as f32 * (radius_bottom - radius_top) + radius_top;

        for x in 0..radial_segments {
            let u = x as f32 / radial_segments as f32;
            let u1 = (x as f32 + 0.5) / radial_segments as f32;

            let theta = u * THETA_END + THETA_START;
            let theta1 = u1 * THETA_END + THETA_START;

            let sin_theta = theta.sin();
            let cos_theta = theta.cos();

            let sin_theta1 = theta1.sin();
            let cos_theta1 = theta1.cos();

            verts.push(Vertex {
                position: [
                    radius * sin_theta,
                    -(y as f32) * height + half_height,
                    radius * cos_theta,
                ],
                normal: [sin_theta1, slope, cos_theta1],
            });
        }

        for x in 1..(radial_segments + 1) {
            let u = x as f32 / radial_segments as f32;
            let u2 = (x as f32 - 0.5) / radial_segments as f32;

            let theta = u * THETA_END + THETA_START;
            let theta2 = u2 * THETA_END + THETA_START;

            let sin_theta = theta.sin();
            let cos_theta = theta.cos();

            let sin_theta2 = theta2.sin();
            let cos_theta2 = theta2.cos();

            verts.push(Vertex {
                position: [
                    radius * sin_theta,
                    -(y as f32) * height + half_height,
                    radius * cos_theta,
                ],
                normal: [sin_theta2, slope, cos_theta2],
            });
        }
    }

    for i in 0..radial_segments {
        let a = i;
        let b = i + radial_segments;
        let c = i + radial_segments * 3;
        let d = i + radial_segments * 2;

        // The first triangle of the radial segment.
        inds.push(b);
        inds.push(a);
        inds.push(d);

        // The second triangle of the radial segment.
        inds.push(c);
        inds.push(b);
        inds.push(d);
    }

    println!("{:.1?}", verts);
    println!("{:?}", inds);
}
```

for the sake of completeness here are the constants and the struct used within the function above:

```rust
const THETA_START: f32 = 0f32;
const THETA_END: f32 = 2f32 * std::f32::consts::PI;

const HEIGHT_SEGMENTS: u32 = 1;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Vertex {
    #[allow(unused)]
    position: [f32; 3],

    #[allow(unused)]
    normal: [f32; 3],
}
```

The desired output of the function for an input of `print_cylinder_vertices(1f32, 1f32, 1f32, 3);` would be:

```
[Vertex { position: [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], normal: [0.9, 0.0, 0.5] }, Vertex { position: [0.9, 0.5, -0.5], normal: [-0.0, 0.0, -1.0] }, Vertex { position: [-0.9, 0.5, -0.5], normal: [-0.9, 0.0, 0.5] }, Vertex { position: [0.9, 0.5, -0.5], normal: [0.9, 0.0, 0.5] }, Vertex { position: [-0.9, 0.5, -0.5], normal: [-0.0, 0.0, -1.0] }, Vertex { position: [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], normal: [-0.9, 0.0, 0.5] }, Vertex { position: [0.0, -0.5, 1.0], normal: [0.9, 0.0, 0.5] }, Vertex { position: [0.9, -0.5, -0.5], normal: [-0.0, 0.0, -1.0] }, Vertex { position: [-0.9, -0.5, -0.5], normal: [-0.9, 0.0, 0.5] }, Vertex { position: [0.9, -0.5, -0.5], normal: [0.9, 0.0, 0.5] }, Vertex { position: [-0.9, -0.5, -0.5], normal: [-0.0, 0.0, -1.0] }, Vertex { position: [0.0, -0.5, 1.0], normal: [-0.9, 0.0, 0.5] }]
[3, 0, 6, 9, 3, 6, 4, 1, 7, 10, 4, 7, 5, 2, 8, 11, 5, 8]
```

I also made a [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=08f1e76a067f56f884a0dc4e409aeb4f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Separate generating the mesh from printing the mesh. i.e. return a `Mesh` class from the generator function and write a separate `print_mesh` function.
- I don't think a shape with two radii would normally be described as a cylinder (I think "frustum" is the correct term). Consider providing various associated `new_` functions for the `Mesh` class to generate different shapes e.g. `new_cylinder`, `new_frustum`, `new_cone`. These would take the appropriate parameters for the various names, and forward to a single function behind the scenes (maybe called `new_conic_frustum` or something).
- Add some documentation. A user is likely to want more info when calling a function like this: How is the shape oriented? Is it centered at the origin, or does it use the origin as a base-line, etc.
- Consider splitting up the `Vertex` class, and having separate vectors for `positions`, `normals`, etc. This is more efficient if we want to skip generating the normals (or UVs, or tangents or whatever if we add them in future).
- `const THETA_END: f32 = 2f32 * std::f32::consts::PI;` this already exists, and is called tau: `std::f32::consts::TAU`.
- The constants `THETA_START`, `THETA_END` and `HEIGHT_SEGMENTS` would probably be better as function arguments.
- `let sin_theta = theta.sin();` We could just write this inline, there's no point making it a variable.
- It looks like the generation of the indices doesn't handle values of `HEIGHT_SEGMENTS` other than `1`. So providing `HEIGHT_SEGMENTS` (even as a constant) is misleading.
- (Note: I actually disagree with the other answer, and think that plain loops are much clearer in this case. I also think it mis-characterizes "functional" programming).

Comment: I agree with a lot of your points (actually most I have already done, but left out for the question because I thought it would be better to have a "closed off" sample). You are right, that currently `HEIGHT_SEGMENTS` can only be one. 

I would be interested in what you mean with "duplicating vertex data unnecessarily"? I thought I need to duplicate the vertices in order to get flat normals (I do not want them to be interpolated on the GPU, and my setup does not support flat shading). Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You're right. I didn't realise the normals were different, so I've removed that part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I won't dive into the algorithm; it looks fine to me at a glance, but I'm not familiar with geometry.

I made a functional version of your code. You won't go far without functional programming in Rust; you'd write code C-style that way. I took out a common factor from both loops and put it into `map`. I took out the difference and put it into `iter::repeat`.

```rust
use std::iter;

fn print_cylinder_vertices(
    radius_bottom: f32, 
    radius_top: f32, 
    height: f32, 
    radial_segments: u32
) {
    // The vertices and indices of the cylinder barrel.
    let mut verts = Vec::new();
    let mut inds = Vec::new();

    // Helper variables.
    let half_height = height / 2f32;

    // Calculate the slope so that the normals can be easily derived.
    let slope = (radius_bottom - radius_top) / height;

    let height_range = 0 ..= HEIGHT_SEGMENTS;
    let radial_segments_x_and_diff = (
        (0 .. radial_segments).zip(iter::repeat(0.5))
    ).chain(
        (1 .. radial_segments + 1).zip(iter::repeat(-0.5))
    );
    let get_radius = |y| y as f32 * (radius_bottom - radius_top) + radius_top;

    verts.extend(
        height_range.flat_map(|y| {
            radial_segments_x_and_diff.clone().zip(iter::repeat((y, get_radius(y))))
        }).map(|((x, normal_diff), (y, radius))| {
            let u = x as f32 / radial_segments as f32;
            let u1 = (x as f32 + normal_diff) / radial_segments as f32;

            let theta = u * THETA_END + THETA_START;
            let theta1 = u1 * THETA_END + THETA_START;

            let sin_theta = theta.sin();
            let cos_theta = theta.cos();

            let sin_theta1 = theta1.sin();
            let cos_theta1 = theta1.cos();

            Vertex {
                position: [
                    radius * sin_theta,
                    -(y as f32) * height + half_height,
                    radius * cos_theta,
                ],
                normal: [sin_theta1, slope, cos_theta1],
            }
        })
    );

    for i in 0..radial_segments {
        let a = i;
        let b = i + radial_segments;
        let c = i + radial_segments * 3;
        let d = i + radial_segments * 2;

        // The first triangle of the radial segment.
        inds.push(b);
        inds.push(a);
        inds.push(d);

        // The second triangle of the radial segment.
        inds.push(c);
        inds.push(b);
        inds.push(d);
    }

    println!("{:.1?}", verts);
    println!("{:?}", inds);
}

const THETA_START: f32 = 0f32;
const THETA_END: f32 = 2f32 * std::f32::consts::PI;

const HEIGHT_SEGMENTS: u32 = 1;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Vertex {
    #[allow(unused)]
    position: [f32; 3],

    #[allow(unused)]
    normal: [f32; 3],
}

fn main() {
    print_cylinder_vertices(1f32, 1f32, 1f32, 3);
}
```

Comment: I was mainly interested in eliminating the second loop, so that I do not have to calculate the values twice as stated in my question. In doing so my hope was to maybe improve the runtime performance a bit. Sadly your approach results in poorer performance (around 5% slower).